# Error I get when I try install IDE Anjuta

Tags: linux, command-line, gnome, gtk3

`sudo apt-get install anjuta`

*Error I get while installing the IDE. What is this error about? However, I am able to successfully install the IDE*

```
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by a KDE library adding custom MIME types.

Fix it with:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/mime/packages/kde.xml /usr/share/mime/packages/kde.xml.bak
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```